# TypeError: loadedCategories.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and i'm trying to display a list of category posts after getting successful data with Axios.

But i meet an error TypeError: loadedCategories.map is not a function
.
I have read some solution but not find the answer right now.

Here my code :

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const NewCategory = () => {
    const [loadedCategories, setloadedCategories] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const getCategoriesData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(
                    "http://localhost:5000/api/category/all-category"
                );
                console.log(response);
                const responseData = response.data;
                setloadedCategories(responseData);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };
        getCategoriesData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <ul>
            {loadedCategories &&
                loadedCategories.map((categories) => {
                    return (
                        <li key={categories.id}>
                            <span>{categories.name}</span>
                        </li>
                    );
                })}
        </ul>
    );
};
export default NewCategory;
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use asynchronous function to get this data and it takes some time to get it, you have to secure your `.map` function to be able to use it. So you not only need to check if `loadedCategories` are not `null` or `undefined` because you set them to empty array on initial so it will pass. You have to check if array has some elements and then `.map` over them. So changing it to:

```
{loadedCategories && loadedCategories.length > 0 &&
           loadedCategories.map((categories) => {
```

Should work here :)

there is also shorter version:

```
 {loadedCategories?.length > 0 &&
           loadedCategories.map((categories) => {
```

Comment: I changed my code as you say . But I don't see any data in my screen although when I open my console in Chrome Dev Tool , I get a list of data in this. Can you have any solution for this case?

Comment: @vtpqui are you sure that `const responseData = response.data` is the `json` format that you need?

Comment: I found the solution. I use fetch instead axios and get the data as I expected. But I still don't understand why it doesn't work with axios.

Comment: @vtpqui axios works little different and gets you data in different form, that is probably why, you should check the docs

Comment: thanks you very much